# Deduplicating rows in BigQuery based on condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently trying to deduplicate rows within Google BigQuery for one of my tables. Basically, I have a table which bas rows containing duplicate values except for one single column. One example would be:

[image]

Please notice that all columns, except for the column "Ad group name" are the same. What I would like to do, is the following: keep a single row (wouldn't matter which one) if all columns **are the same** but the column ad group name is **different**.

I was thinking of creating partitions and using a rank function to denotate different values within that partition. Something like:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Adgroup ID, date, Sales, Cost ORDER BY Ad group name) AS rank
```

Theoretically (hehe) this should lead to something like:

[image]

Using this I could filter in a new subquery using `WHERE Rank = 1`. This would remove all the duplicate rows in that case.

However, I'm finding that BigQuery doesn't support using FLOAT64 for partitioning, so my solution doesn't work. Also, I think there's a better way to do this but I'm having trouble finding out on how to do that. Which function in BigQuery can I leverage for this specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` for this purpose:

```
select Adgroup ID, date, Sales, Cost, any_value(ad_group_name)
from t
group by Adgroup ID, date, Sales, Cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions for this case.
One using `partition by` with `analytic function` and the other using `group by` with `ARRAY_AGG()`.

(possible solutions of avoiding `GROUP BY` with `any_value`)

1. ANALYTIC FUNCTION `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH
org_table AS (
    SELECT 15840 as AdGroupID, '22-1-2019' as AdDate, 'TVs' as AdGroupName, 800 as Sales, 200 as Cost
    UNION ALL SELECT 15840 as AdGroupID, '22-1-2019' as AdDate, 'Televisions' as AdGroupName, 800 as Sales, 200 as Cost
)
SELECT *
FROM org_table
WHERE TRUE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdgroupID ORDER BY AdDate DESC) = 1
;
```

2. `GROUP BY` with `AGG_ARRAY`

```
WITH
org_table AS (
    SELECT 15840 as AdGroupID, '22-1-2019' as AdDate, 'TVs' as AdGroupName, 800 as Sales, 200 as Cost
    UNION ALL SELECT 15840 as AdGroupID, '22-1-2019' as AdDate, 'Televisions' as AdGroupName, 800 as Sales, 200 as Cost
)
SELECT
    AdgroupID,  -- primary key
    ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(AdDate, AdGroupName, Sales, Cost)
        ORDER BY AdGroupName ASC LIMIT 1
    )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM org_table
GROUP BY AdgroupID
;
```